# The plain English justification of the use of "such that" in mathematics?

Tags: phrase-usage

In mathematics the phrase "such that" is used to specify conditions on objects. For example, "There is an integer *x* such that *x* + 3 = 5" is a typical mathematical statement.

However, since the example sentence is equivalent to "There is an integer that plus 3 equals 5", I have been tempted to boldly assert that the example sentence is also equivalent to "There is an integer such that this integer plus 3 equals 5". Then, we can in turn say "There is a girl with a big bag" to mean "There is a girl such that this girl has a big bag".

Is the above argument right? I am not sure, since I am not a native speaker in English, if the use of "such that" is consistent with plain English grammar?

Comment: Not quite; *with* phrases like this are not used predicatively, so you have to say "There is a girl such that this girl **has** a big bag." In any case, the *such that* construction is pretty much confined to mathematical and logical discourse where the purpose is to investigate the entailments of the existence of a girl of that sort.

Comment: @StoneyB: Ah, right :) I should have written it clear enough. So, if you are a native speaker, would you feel that the sentence "There is a girl such that this girl has a big bag" is okay for reading?

Answer (score 2):

> There is a girl such that this girl has a big bag

This is awkward.  "Such that" is typically used only in legal, mathematical or technical contexts.

Also, "such that" is used to provide a qualifying condition on something indefinite.  Since you are talking about a specific girl that's observable or known to the listener/reader, avoid using "such that."

> A girl such that she has a big bag may be hiding something

This is more in line with how "such that" works but still odd sounding because it's not a legal, mathematical, or technical context.

So this:

> A block such that it is four inches on each side is required.

makes sense, and it sounds like something you might find in an engineering proprosal or similar.

But never

> This block such that it is four inches on each side is required